# Deploy Outlook Add-in -Yeoman-

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, yeoman, office-addins, yeoman-generator

I need guidance for deploying an outlook add-in created by Yeoman.
I am new to this.  I already tried uploading the whole project generated by Yeoman to Heroku and according to Heroku, it deployed successfully. But I don't know what else I should do. I am confused.

Should I upload to the server the project without the manifest? because the manifest is the one that I will place in office to install the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server can host only the web app. It is up to you where to store the manifest file. The manifest file is for sideloading or publishing to the AppSource. Read more about that in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) section of MSDN.